# css: content box crossing fixed footer box

Tags: html, css, layout

I have fixed footer DIV and content DIV. Footer DIV is fixed so it is visible all time. Content DIV is 100% height, but it touches footer DIV and crosses it to the end. I want it just to end when footer begins.

```
<div id="footer">
</div>

<div id="content">
</div>
```

Here is a *jsFiddle* link: http://jsfiddle.net/MXMWe/3/

**Problem:** Content DIV (with its text) goes over footer.

**Note 1:** Footer has to be visible all time no matter where you scroll (possibly fixed.

**Note 2:** Scrollbars have to be normal as it is when you first load browser. No changes there.

Here is an *image* telling what I want to achieve:
[image]

I will give more info if asked.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try to add padding or margin bottom in your #content equal to your footer height. In your fiddle, I was able to display your expected results by removing the #content height/min-height and then add a padding-bottom:120px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MXMWe/4/

A few things:

1. I added a `<div id="footer-padding></div>` before the closing div in `#content`. Then in the css added `height:120px;` (the same height as the `#footer` ) - This allows the content text to not be stuck at the bottom of the site, but instead the very top of the footer.
2. I removed the opacity that was on the footer because if you have the opacity it effects the entire div - AKA the text from the content div would be visible behind it since it's transparent.
3. I added a `z-index: 2` to the `#footer` to ensure it is above the `#content` at all times.

If you're going to have an opacity/transparency as the background of the footer you will see  anything it's above, behind it.

Comment: z-index is not a trick here. Opacity was meant to demonstrate if text was put behind the footer. It's not a solution, but thanks for your time.

Comment: Well with fixed, text will always go behind based on browser size... The #footer-padding allows the text to be visible once scrolled... Add the opacity back to my jsfiddle and you will see the text is never hidden once scrolled down all the way.

Comment: It makes no sense. If you make a a content box bordered, then the border won't be visible, it will simply be downwards, behind the footer. Take an example of putting another DIV between footer and content, it cannot be achieved in a way you presented your example.

Comment: Put however many divs after content you want - you just need to know there needs to be some sort of "footer-padding" div that is the same height as the footer so content never gets stuck behind the footer if you scroll down.  http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Comment: And based on browser size and content - there is no way to only have content above footer at all times. If you have 1 line of text you can do it with almost any browser size/device, but that's not realistic. The only other possible way is to create a div with static height and width with overflow:scroll

Comment: That's already a point. Giving upvote and waiting. If no answer will be posted I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the [CSS Sticky Footer](http://cssstickyfooter.com)?

Comment: I don't want a sticky footer at all. There is no problem with footer. It's visible at all times. It's called CSS Fixed Footer.